What is the difference between sample space and support of a random vairbale?
All is in the question ;-) I understand the sample space as the set of possible outcomes and the support as the set of outcomes associated to a non-zero probability (in the discrete case). I read an example where someone considered a biased-towards-even 6-faces dice and say the sample space is $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ while the support is only $\{2, 4, 6\}$. But if the dice is assumed to be biased and only produces even outcomes, are the odd values still worth to be included in the sample space, defined as the set of possible outcomes ?
I don't really get the difference, I guess it is subtle and even maybe something more philosophical than mathematical at the end of the day.
Can you confirm it ? My intuition is that it is a bit similar to the distinction codomain/image for example
In the continuous case, this seems even more intricated for me. Again, can you confirm or give a clear example where the difference matters ?

The sample space can indeed be larger than the support.

When you are contemplating just a single random variable to reason about data, the distinction is usually immaterial.  But when other random variables are involved, the distinction is far more than a merely philosophical one!

@whuber can you elaborate ?

I have done so many times: see this site search.
